# Datastax Opscenter requires restart when JMX auth is enabled?

Tags: docker, cassandra, datastax, opscenter, nosql

I have a Cassandra 2.2 cluster and a Opscenter 5.2 instance (called `opsc`) running in docker.

After the Cassandra cluster has started **with JMX auth enabled** (before starting `opsc`), the Opscenter agent's log shows

```
 ERROR [async-dispatch-1] 2015-08-11 22:45:45,241 Uncaught exception on async-dispatch-1
 java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:211)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticate(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:163)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.authenticate(ConnectorBootstrap.java:219)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:232)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(RMIServerImpl.java:199)
```

which is as expected because JMX auth is enabled, but the agent isn't configured with the credentials (it will receive the credentials from `opsc`).

However, after adding the cluster in the Opscenter UI, Opscenter still can't connect to the cluster.

Here's the log from one Cassandra node:

```
  INFO [qtp176892017-22] 2015-08-11 23:00:16,648 Starting up agent collection.
  INFO [qtp176892017-22] 2015-08-11 23:00:16,648 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 ERROR [qtp176892017-22] 2015-08-11 23:00:16,654 Unhandled route Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
            JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:211 com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure
            JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:163 com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticate
                   ConnectorBootstrap.java:219 sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.authenticate
                        RMIServerImpl.java:232 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient
                        RMIServerImpl.java:199 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
              NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
...
```

And log from `opscenterd.log`:

```
...
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 172.18.100.2 is version '5.2.0'
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster] ERROR: Agent for 172.18.100.2 was unable to complete operation (http://172.18.100.2:61621/load-stomp-conf?): java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 172.18.100.4 is version '5.2.0'
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster] ERROR: Agent for 172.18.100.4 was unable to complete operation (http://172.18.100.4:61621/load-stomp-conf?): java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Agent for ip 172.18.100.3 is version '5.2.0'
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster] ERROR: Agent for 172.18.100.3 was unable to complete operation (http://172.18.100.3:61621/load-stomp-conf?): java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Automatic agent setup failed for ( Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.4)):  Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.4)
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Automatic agent setup failed for ( Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.2)):  Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.2)
2015-08-11 23:00:16+0000 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Automatic agent setup failed for ( Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.3)):  Authentication failed! Credentials required (172.18.100.3)
...
```

Only after restarting the opscenterd service did everything work correctly.

So what's the problem with the JMX auth?  Why is a restart required?  Thanks

**Addition 1**

Restarting the Opscenter agent on each Cassandra node also solved the problem, so I guess it might be because the JMX credential information isn't communicated by Opscenter to the agents.

[Opscenter doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html) says "After changing properties in this file, restart OpsCenter for the changes to take effect.".  Assuming adding a cluster basically changes `cluster_name.conf`, this looks like a design flaw, because the user may not have access to restart Opscenter server (not to mention how disruptive it is).

Comment: “However, after adding the cluster in the Opscenter UI, Opscenter still can't connect to the cluster.” just to make sure, the cluster was not monitored before enabling JMX auth, and you’ve specified JMX credentials while adding the cluster. Correct?

Comment: @arre, yes that's what I did